# Checking Chartio filter for empty string SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, chartio

In my Chartio report, I have a variable filter named **TRACKING_GROUP** with Control Type of **Text Input**, with a Default Value of the empty string.

The following SQL works fine..

```
SELECT
    {TRACKING_GROUP} AS tg,
    (CASE WHEN {TRACKING_GROUP} = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS tg_present
```

..returning..

```
+----+------------+
| tg | tg_present |
+----+------------+
|    | 0          |
+----+------------+
```

When I try and cast the text value to an integer in the `ELSE` condition (which ideally should not be getting reached due to the default value of **TRACKING_GROUP** being the empty string), using the following SQL..

```
SELECT
    {TRACKING_GROUP} AS tg,
    (CASE WHEN {TRACKING_GROUP} = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS tg_present,
    (CASE WHEN {TRACKING_GROUP} = '' THEN 0 ELSE CAST({TRACKING_GROUP} AS INTEGER) END) AS tg_int
```

..I get the following error messages:

> - There was an error extracting data for one or more layers
> - Your database returned: Amazon Invalid operation: invalid input syntax for integer: "";

When this filter has a string value of "10557" for example, no errors occur when running the second query listed above, returning...

```
+-------+------------+--------+
| tg    | tg_present | tg_int |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 10557 | 1          | 10,557 |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

How can I toggle the casting of this filter to an integer when its value is the empty string since Chartio does not like when that happens?

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be to concatenate a zero before the value:  `cast('0' || {TRACKING_GROUP} as INTEGER)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the errors are still getting triggered when I try that.

Comment: what type of database is chartio connected to?